# Transfer data from session to views through laravel middleware

Tags: php, laravel, session, cart

I am retrieving the items which have been added to a cart in a session, and also calculating the total number of items. I create an array to which these items are added, which I use to display the cart. I take the number of items in the cart and display that number in every view. I have the code worked out, but as of now the only way to make it work is to copy and paste it in every route. Research suggests using a middleware is the way to share the variables among all views, but I have been unable to get this to work.

First, here is the code for the middleware.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\Models\Item;

class GetCart
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $items = Item::all();
        $cartItems = [];
        for($i=0; $i < count($items); $i++){
            if(null !== Session::get('cartItem'.$i)){
                $item = Session::get('cartItem'.$i);
                array_push($cartItems, $item);
            }
        };  
        $totalNum = 0;
        for($i=0; $i < count($cartItems); $i++){
            if(isset($cartItems[$i])){
                $totalNum += $cartItems[$i]['quantity'];
            }
        }          
        View::share('cartItems', $cartItems);
        View::share('totalNum', $totalNum);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

In App\Http\Kernel.php, I add it to the $middleware variable, which makes it automatically load at every request.

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\GetCart::class
];
```

However, I am still not able to retrieve the variable. It says 'undefined variable.' So I would appreciate help on what I am missing, as to why I am not able to share this variable among all views. As I said, I can make it work by copying and pasting the code into every route, but I know this is not the proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you already working with the response in your middleware. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#middleware-and-responses
You need it before passing deeper into the application. Then should be available in all views.

But I think it would be better to make a separate blade for the cart (cart.blade.php) and include it in all other views where it is needed. Then make a new view composer class for that cart view and share your `cartItems` and `totalNum` in it.
See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers